# ZF2 Shared Events

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I'm trying to set up an event in one module and trigger it in a controller in another module. I'm using the shared event manager but it seems im doing something wrong..

Module1:

```
public function onBoostrap(Event $e)
        {
              $sem = $e->getTarget()->getEventManager()->getSharedEventManager();
              $sem->attach('checkSomething', function (){
                          die("checked");
              });
        }
```

Module2 controller:

```
 public function checkAction ()
        {
                $this->getEventManager()->trigger('checkSomething');
}
```

Do you guys know what i may be doing wrong? Or if there is a better (correct) way to do this..

Answer (score 3):

The problem in the solution of Yassine is that the event is attached on 'Zend\Mvc\Application'. This event identifier is not available in your controller

You can verify this by executing the following code in a action

```php
print_r($this->getEventManager()->getIdentifiers());
```

the result will be something like

```txt
Array ( 
    [0] => Zend\Stdlib\DispatchableInterface 
    [1] => Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractController 
    [2] => Application\Controller\TestController 
    [3] => Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController 
    [4] => Application 
)
```

Now to solve your problem in you module attach the event to the 'Application' identifier
and then trigger your event in the action.

so:

```php
/*Module*/
public function onBootstrap($e)
{
    $eventManager = $e->getApplication()->getEventManager();
    $sem          = $eventManager->getSharedManager();

    $sem->attach('Application', 'checkSomething', function () {
        echo "checked";
        /* do more stuff here */
    }, 100);

}
```

```php
/* a action in a controller */
$this->getEventManager()->trigger('checkSomething');
```

This should result in

```txt
checked
```

And so you have triggered the event succesfully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the identifier of the resource containing an instance of the event manager. Many classes (Application, ModuleManager...) use their class name as an identifier within their contained EventManager instance.

Your attachment line should then look like this:

```
$sem->attach('Zend\Mvc\Application','checkSomething', function (){
                      die("checked");
          });
```

(Update) From the controller you should call the application EventManager:

```
$this->getServiceLocator()->get('application')->getEventManager()->trigger('chec‌​kSomething');
```

cheers,

Yassine